# Как сменить класс объекту при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript, css

Т.е. смотрите, есть у меня, допустим, div. Типа:

```
<div class='pervyui'></div>
```

И фишка, если класс равен этому, то нужно сменить на другой. Если другому, то на этот. Значит, пишу так:

```
function smena(obj) {
  if (obj.ClassName=='pervuyi') {
    obj.ClassName='vtoroi';
  }
  else
  {
    obj.ClassName='pervuyi';
  }
}
```

Вообщем, писал это по - разному. Пытался с двумя знаками "=", но ничего не получается. Подскажите, как правильно.

А, функцию вызывать пытался так:

```
<div OnClick='smena(this)' class='pervyui'></div>
```

Comment: .classList.remove()/.add() ?


class это атрибут в котором содержится не один какой-то класс а список классов и обращаться надо  с ним соответствующе.

Answer (score 2):

Свойство называется "className", это важно.